# C# and .NET Core: The proper way to add an event handler to an object created by DI

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am adding a service using `.AddTransient` to be injected automatically when it is passed to any constructor. I need to add an event handler when the injected object is created and passed to a constructor of some class.

I used this:

```
   builder.Services
        .AddTransient(factory =>
        {
            var rest = factory.GetService<RestUtilityService>();
            rest.Exception += Api_Exception;
            return rest;
        })
```

But when debugging, that code is called several times and the application hangs.

Can you tell me how to add that event handler when the object is first created?

Of course, the event should be subscribed only once, so it should be done at first, and only, creation.

Thanks

Jaime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is probably unintentionally recursive, you should probably create your object explicitly:

```
builder.Services
        .AddTransient(factory =>
        {
            var rest = new RestUtilityService(factory.GetService<SomeDependency>());
            rest.Exception += Api_Exception;
            return rest;
        })
```

That does not necessarily mean that this is the best approach to solve the problem. If you want some central handling of exceptions it might be better to create a `IExceptionHandler`, declare an implementation of this as a singleton, and make this a dependency of your `RestUtilityService`.

Answer (score 1):

This code will result in a stack overflow exception because the registration is recursively calling itself.

Instead, you might try something as follows:

```cs
   builder.Services
        .AddTransient(factory =>
        {
            var rest = new RestUtilityService();
            rest.Exception += Api_Exception;
            return rest;
        })
```

or:

```cs
   builder.Services
        .AddTransient(factory =>
        {
            var rest = ActivatorUtilities.Create<RestUtilityService>(factory);
            rest.Exception += Api_Exception;
            return rest;
        })
```